# Girl sent back in time by a flying monster to save a boy's life, with an agreement that she'll prevent him falling in love with her

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

I am looking for a manga, but I can't remember the name.

A shy high school girl falls in love with a solitary/delinquent boy in the same class as her. They dated for several years but the boy is then killed. A little flying monster appeared and told her that he can send her to the past, just before they meet, and if she agrees to prevent the boy falling in love with her, he will be saved.

So she goes back to the past and tries to do so...

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember when you read this?

Comment: I have read it about 1 year ago.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: "tries to do so..." and then what?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like ***[I will not get involved with Ichijou Kaname!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=133223)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> This series is a painful love story of a return to the past to erase the first love. Ritsu, the main character, goes back to the past to change the future since her lover Ichijou Kaname is going to die, and she tries her best to avoid him and suppress her love, in order save him.

Ritsu's high school sweetheart, Kaname, dies when he's struck by a car. Afterwards, she's lying in bed, wondering what she could've done differently to prevent his death, when a small flying creature wearing a top hat and monocle appears, and tells her that he can rewind time for her, but that in order to save Kaname, she needs to avoid getting involved with him altogether. She agrees, and sets out to do just that.

[image]

[image]